# UIImageView category to download images with GCD fails with a large number simultaneous downloads

Tags: objective-c, uiimageview, grand-central-dispatch

I've used AFNetworking to download and cache images in my project, but I wanted to replace the framework with a lightest in-house category, obviously I'm facing a lot of issues with dispatch queues, and I'm having a hard time debugging them.

This is the [category](https://gist.github.com/dev-mush/70b935a44d34ec4c7af4) I'm using right now, It works with no problem with a small number of simultaneous downloads but, if I start a lot of downloads it looks like the application hangs an an endless load.

I need some help debugging and I would like to understand what I'm missing here.

Here are the two main functions:

```
- (void) imageWithUrl: (NSURL*) imageUrl placeHolderImage: (UIImage *) placeHolderImage shouldAlwaysRefresh: (BOOL) shouldRefresh {

    self.image= placeHolderImage;

    TMCache *sharedCache = [TMCache sharedCache];
    [sharedCache trimToDate: [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow: -(60.0*24.0*7.0)]];

    UIImage *cachedImage = [sharedCache objectForKey: [imageUrl absoluteString]];

    if(cachedImage){
        self.image = cachedImage;

        if(shouldRefresh)
            [self fetchImageFromUrl: imageUrl];
    }
    else{
        [self fetchImageFromUrl: imageUrl];
    }
}
```

---

```
- (void) fetchImageFromUrl: (NSURL *) imageUrl{

    dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0);

    dispatch_async(queue, ^{

        NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:imageUrl];

        UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];

        if(image){

            [[TMCache sharedCache] setObject:image forKey: [imageUrl absoluteString]];

            dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                self.image = image;
            });


        }
    });

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is most likely the `dispatch_sync` back to the main queue creating a [deadlock](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deadlock) when the image has finished loading.

The easiest way to solve that is to simply replace your `dispatch_sync` with `dispatch_async`.

```
if(image) {
    [[TMCache sharedCache] setObject:image forKey: [imageUrl absoluteString]];

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        self.image = image;
    });
}
```

I don't see any reason to use a `dispatch_sync` there since you're already in a `dispatch_async` block; this shouldn't have any negative effects on your code. If fact, you should usually try to avoid using `dispatch_sync` if at all possible, precisely for the issue you're running in to here.

---

***Sidenote:** AFNetworking actually gives you quite a bit for not all that much code. I'd seriously think twice before using your own solution over AFNetworking.*

Comment: this was my first guess but, unluckily, nothing changes.

Comment: when it hangs, have you paused your application in Xcode to see what it's trying to execute?

Comment: when I pause the debugger it places on semaphore_wait_trap, I have 71 threads spawned...I'm pretty sure it is a deadlock, and of course I'm sure I'd rather be using AFNetworking to make myself a favour... that said I'd like to understand what has been my mistake.

Comment: That definitely sounds like a deadlock. Is your main thread/queue waiting on `semaphore_wait_trap`, or is it just the other threads? Do you have any other GCD code in your app that could be deadlocking ?

Comment: Apparently every thread is on semaphore_wait_trap, plus... looks like I'm having other networking with Parse framework presumably caused by this.

Comment: You might want to try making a simple test project that uses this code to isolate the issue.